# Parsed Uri has wrong port number

Tags: c#, uri

Consider the code, assuming `baseUri` comes from a method parameter

```
    Uri baseUri = new Uri("www.contoso.com:8080/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    baseUri = baseUri.IsAbsoluteUri
            ? baseUri
            : new Uri("http://" + baseUri.OriginalString);//make URI http by default
    Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
```

For the given string IsAbsoluteUri returns true. But despite the port is specified right in the URI `myUri.Port` is -1 and myUri.Host is empty.

How should I parse this string to get the correct port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `http://` to the start of your base uri string to make it a valid URI e.g:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PB5njq)

Comment: was just about to write this and you beat me to it

Comment: As I mentioned baseUri comes from user input. It can be http://, https://, ftp:// etc.
I can not just add protocol. Thats why I've tried to detect if I need to add it by reading IsAbsoluteUri property

Comment: if it comes in incorrect you'll get vague data - after all its supposed to guess ftp http https?

Comment: @AskNReply What is your point? If the uri comes from user input you will obviously want to validate that it's a correct URI containing the scheme.

Comment: 2BugFinder. Uri comes in correct form. If you try
`Uri.TryCreate("www.contoso.com:8080/", UriKind.Absolute, out baseUri);`
you will get wellformed object.

Comment: DGibbs, URI comes validated already. `"www.contoso.com:8080/"` looks like a valid one for System.Uri. I mentioned above how validation is done. You can propose your validation approach.

Comment: @AskNReply If as you say the input comes from the user and the URI can be to 'ftp/https/http' etc... `"As I mentioned baseUri comes from user input. It can be http://, https://, ftp:// etc."` - then how are you supposed to determine what scheme to get the resource under? You should validate the user input before it reaches this method, check if it starts with a scheme or provide a drop down or something next to the field to allow them to select it from a list. Then prepend it to the rest of the uri.

Comment: Also, this line `new Uri("http://" + baseUri.OriginalString);` is going to break if you provide a relative path as the base uri e.g. `/index.html` will give `http:///index.html`.

Comment: `You should validate the user input before it reaches this method` how am I supposed to do it? So far Uri.TryCreate is used for validation. Manual parsing (eg `String.StartsWith("http://"`)) is the thing I want to avoid.

Comment: @AskNReply Right, and how is `Uri.TryCreate` supposed to know what scheme `foo.com` is using? It could be ftp, it could be https, it doesn't care. All it is concerned with is whether the input is a valid URI. You don't need to use `StartsWith()` but you should probably provide some way for the user to select the scheme on the front end or choose whether it's relative or not.

Comment: `is Uri.TryCreate supposed to know what scheme foo.com is using?` - seem so. I expected to get `false`, but Uri.TryCreate thinks different and returns broken object.

Comment: @AskNReply If the scheme is not provided in the input how is it supposed to know?

Comment: No it does not. If the scheme is not provided Uri.TryCreate should return false. But it returns true and broken object. Thats the point.

Comment: @AskNReply `"If the scheme is not provided Uri.TryCreate should return false"` nope. Scheme is not required, consider relative paths for example.

Comment: @DGibbs, if case of relative path parsed port number in my sample should be `8080`. In fact it is `-1`

Comment: @AskNReply Right? Except your example shows an absolute path though, not a relative one. As discussed in my answer, you need to provide the scheme along with an absolute path for it to pick up the port correctly. `-1` indicates port not found. And if you step through the code you can see the port number being incorrectly interpreted as part of the path. Give the user a way to select absolute or relative path and let them choose the scheme is probably the best solution.